# reusing existing named query by adding a condition on top of it, instead of repeating the complete query in hibernate

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hibernate, orm

Is there any way we can reuse (by adding a condition on top of existing query)  the named query (i.e.  tag being used to define namedQuery in .hbm file in hibernate).? For example:
Let say, I am defining a named query in .hbm file

```
<sql-query name="existingQuery">
        <return alias="queryNumber1" class="com.xyz.Person"/>
        <![CDATA[ **select country, name from person where date_of_birth >== TO_DATE(CONCAT (:dateOfBirth,'00:00:00'), 'YYYY/MM/DDHH24:MI:SS')**]]>
    </sql-query>
```

now I need another named query (projecting same set of attribute with on additional condition.

```
<sql-query name="newQuery">
        <return alias="queryNumber2" class="com.xyz.Person"/>
        <![CDATA[ **select country, name from person where date_of_birth >== TO_DATE(CONCAT (:dateOfBirth,'00:00:00'), 'YYYY/MM/DDHH24:MI:SS')** and age > :age ]]>
    </sql-query>
```

Is there any way, I can avoid the highlighted duplication in database query side (i.e. I can use reuse "existingQuery" for "newQuery") . I does not want to filter in the java code. ?

Comment: I've edited your question so that people can read the embedded code. Please format your  questions appropriately in the future.

Comment: thanks @coDe murDerer